# CORS blocking iTunes api for angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am trying to get some data from iTunes api. But I am getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
api.service.ts:39 0
api.service.ts:42 Something is wrong!
zone.js:3243 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake with MIME type text/javascript. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

Any idea's? I have tried proxy.conf.json approach but was unsuccessful.

my service.ts is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  api: string = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  public getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.api)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api url needs to be:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=drake&enitity=album
```

That fixed it

Comment: This solved the issue for me as well. Thanks.